# How to fix a implicit declaration error in C99?

Tags: c, c99

I can't understand why I am getting this error surrounding the getline() call. I have imported stdlib.h but I am still getting an "implicit decleration" error.

The error is as follows:

```
mopsolver.c: In function ‘take_input’:
mopsolver.c:54:35: error: passing argument 1 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     while ( 0 < (count = getline( &buf, &len, stdin)) ) {
                                   ^

mopsolver.c:21:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 int getline(char line[], int maxline);
     ^~~~~~~
mopsolver.c:54:41: error: passing argument 2 of ‘getline’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     while ( 0 < (count = getline( &buf, &len, stdin)) ) {
                                         ^

mopsolver.c:21:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘size_t * {aka long unsigned int *}’
 int getline(char line[], int maxline);
     ^~~~~~~

mopsolver.c:54:26: error: too many arguments to function ‘getline’
     while ( 0 < (count = getline( &buf, &len, stdin)) ) {
                          ^~~~~~~
```

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "myQueue.h"

#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#define MAXQUEUE 256
int intArray[MAXQUEUE];
int itemCount = 0;

//This struct is created for each space in the map
typedef struct Space{
    char character;
    bool isVisited;
}Space;

/*
 * This function prints out the help menu to the standard input
 */
void help_menu(){
    printf("\n");
    printf("USAGE:\n");
    printf("mopsolver [-hdsp] [-i INFILE] [-o OUTFILE]\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("        -h      Print this helpful message to stdout and exit.\n");
    printf("        -d      Pretty print (display) the maze after reading.  (Default: off)\n");
    printf("        -s      Print shortest solution steps.        \t\t(Default: off)\n");
    printf("        -p      Print an optimal path.                \t\t(Default: off)\n");
    printf("        -i INFILE       Read maze from INFILE.        \t\t(Default: stdin)\n");
    printf("        -o OUTFILE      Write all output to OUTFILE.  \t\t(Default: stdout)\n\n");
}

int take_input(){
    char * buf = NULL;
    char *fileName=optarg;
    size_t len = 0;
    int count = 0;
    FILE * fp = fopen( fileName, "r");
    assert(fp);

    while ( 0 < (count = getline( &buf, &len, stdin)) ) {
        char * tok = strtok( buf, " \t\n");
        while ( tok ) {
            printf( "%c ", *tok);
            tok = strtok( NULL, " \n");
        }
        printf( "\n");
    }
    printf( "last count == %d\n", count);
    free( buf);
    fclose( fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv []){
    //The options for the flags
    int opt;

    //checks to see if we were passed in the correct number of input
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "usage: getfile filename\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //define {row,col}
    int N,M = 0;

    //checks the flags inputed
    while ((opt = getopt(argc  ,argv,"hdspi:o:")) != -1){
        switch (opt){
            case 'd':
                //pretty print
                take_input();
                break;
            case 'h':
                //help
                help_menu();
                break;
            case 's':
                //shortest solution

                break;
            case 'p':
                //optimal path

                break;
            case 'o':
                //output

                break;
            case 'i':
                //input
                take_input();
                break;
            default:break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to fix this but nothing seems to work. C noob here please help:/

Comment: Where do you see "implicit declaration" anywhere?

Comment: Can't reproduce. There is no error for `getline` (although there are other issues with this code)

Comment: Yes I know what too many arguments mean, but I believe I am giving the correct number of arguments:

Comment: I updated to show all the errors I am getting

Comment: `getline` is not a C standard function, so it won't be declared by default in conforming mode. (And when it's declared, it's in `<stdio.h>`, not `<stdlib.h>`.)

Comment: @jack: the errors you pasted do not correspond to the code. Those errors are the result of an attempt you made to fix the original error by explicitly declaring `getline`; it didn't work because you used the wrong declaration. It is really important that code, errors, and output (if applicable) are all exactly the same version of the code. Otherwise, your question becomes confusing and downvotes are likely (as in this case). Please check twice for consistency before hitting the "Post" button.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the section "Feature test macros requirements" in the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

```
   getline(), getdelim():
       Since glibc 2.10:
           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
```

What this means is that you need to put

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

*before* all your `#include` statements. (I.e.at the beginning of the source file). If you don't do this, the header file will not declare `getline` or `getdelim`.